# how can I get the range of the time is last month but the time is a number data type?

Tags: sql, oracle

Regarding to the previous question I have asked, i learnt that how to get the last month data in sql, here is my code:

```
EXTRACT(month FROM CURRENT_DATE)-1 = EXTRACT(month FROM LOG_DTM) and 
EXTRACT(year FROM CU RRENT_DATE) = EXTRACT(year FROM LOG_DTM)
```

However, if the data type of `LOG_DTM` is changed into a number, not a time. So now `LOG_DTM` is the date and `LOG_DTM_ID` is a number which is based on the `LOG_DTM`

For example,
if the date is `2022-09-30`, then `LOG_DTM` = `'2022-09-30'` but `LOG_DTM_ID` is a serious of number `20220930`. My code isn't working anymore.

I try to do it add to_number(), but it seems doesn't work.
any direciton and ideas? Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

> if the data type of LOG_DTM is changed into a number, ...

... then convert it to a valid `DATE` datatype value (use `to_date`, not `to_number` to do that; of course, with appropriate format model):

```
extract(month from current_date) - 1 = extract(month from to_date(log_dtm, 'yyyymmdd'))
```

Comment: Just change `to_date(log_dtm, 'yyyymmdd')` to  `to_date(log_dtm_id, 'yyyymmdd')`

Comment: @Chetan, question is kind of difficult to understand. Sentence I quoted suggests that LOG_DTM is a NUMBER now. The rest of question says that it is, actually, LOG_DTM_ID. I can't tell for sure which one is it, but the principle is just the same. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: It seems not working, it said:

`ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"`

Comment: Now I tried in that way, my target is LOG_DTM and LOG_DTM_ID is last month:

`AND EXTRACT(month FROM CURRENT_DATE)-1 = EXTRACT(month FROM LOG_DTM) and 
EXTRACT(year FROM CURRENT_DATE) = EXTRACT(year FROM LOG_DTM)
AND extract(month from current_date) - 1 = extract(month from to_date(LOG_DTM_ID, 'yyyymmdd'))`



IT does work, any problems here?

Comment: Then not all values follow format you specified, i.e. YYYYMMDD. You'll have to fix data if you want to use such a query.

Comment: But, why are you keeping the same information in two columns? What's the benefit? In my opinion, there should be only **one column** whose datatype is **DATE**.

Comment: becuase LOG_DTM_ID has a index, it is better to search the data with log_DTM and log_DTM_ID. Otherwise, if i search log_DTM only, I have to scan the whole table. It takes very long time. Unfortunatley, I am still not figuring out

Comment: Index makes sense. But, why didn't you create index on DATE datatype column, LOG_DTM? Why do you think that you need a NUMBER datatype column for that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert NUMBER to DATE you can use TO_DATE function:

```
EXTRACT(month FROM CURRENT_DATE)-1 = EXTRACT(month FROM to_date(LOG_DTM,'yyyy-mm-dd')) and 
EXTRACT(year FROM CURRENT_DATE) = EXTRACT(year FROM to_date(LOG_DTM,'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```